# android JNI, how to use use findViewById

Tags: android, java-native-interface

What would be the code to call `findViewById` in C++? What is `ID` type in C++? string, integer, pointer? What is a signature for GetMethodID?

```
string ID = "sample id";
jFindViewById = (env)->GetMethodID(cls, "findViewById", "ILjava/lang/Id;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
jobject myView = (jobject) (env)->CallObjectMethod(Obj, jFindViewById, ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer myself, it was not very obvious but I got it after one hour of trial and error. Hope it could be helpful for others.

```
your jni funcion declaration... (JNIEnv* env, jobject Obj) {
   jmethodID jfindViewById = 0;
   int ID = 2; //get the ID somewhere else, it is just an integer.
   jfindViewById = (env)->GetMethodID(cls, "findViewById", "(I)Landroid/view/View;");
   jobject image_view = (jobject) (env)->CallObjectMethod(Obj, jfindViewById, ID);
}
```